# Youtube Data API Search - Next page token is None after 11 pages

Tags: python, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to capture channel ids of all channels with q = "news" category; there are total of 36714 results but for some reason, the next page token keeps showing None after a few pages for me.
Can someone please check my code, am I doing something wrong

```
#Code

ChannelCategory = "news"

import pandas as pd
from csv import writer


def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
        # Create a writer object from csv module
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)


def get_channel_data(youtube,ChannelCategory):
    page_iteration = 0
    all_data = []
    request = youtube.search().list(
                part="snippet",
                channelType="any",
                maxResults=50,
                q= ChannelCategory,
                order="date",
                type="channel"
                )
    response = request.execute()
    #CSV creation
    append_list_as_row('channel_data1.csv', ['channelId', 'description', 'channelTitle'])
    
    #loop through 50 items -- Following in the list
    for item in response['items']:
        data = [
            item['snippet']['channelId'],
            item['snippet']['description'],
            item['snippet']['title']
            ]
        
        #all_data.append(data) adding in csv
        append_list_as_row('channel_data1.csv', data)
    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
    print('After first 50 - next token is ', next_page_token)
    more_pages = True
    
    while more_pages:
        if next_page_token is None:
            more_pages = False
        else:
            request = youtube.search().list(
                        part="snippet",
                        channelType="any",
                        maxResults=50,
                        q= ChannelCategory,
                        order="date",
                        pageToken = next_page_token,
                        type="channel"
                        )
            response = request.execute()
            
            for item in response['items']:
                data = [
                    item['snippet']['channelId'],
                    item['snippet']['description'],
                    item['snippet']['title']
                    ]

                #all_data.append(data) adding in csv
                append_list_as_row('channel_data1.csv', data)
                
            next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
            page_iteration = page_iteration +1
            print(next_page_token)
            if page_iteration == 20:
                more_pages = False
   print(next_page_token)    
   return(pd.DataFrame(all_data))
```

the output that I get of above code is below

After first 50 - next token is  CDIQAA
CGQQAA
CJYBEAA
CMgBEAA
CPoBEAA
CKwCEAA
CN4CEAA
CJADEAA
CMIDEAA
CPQDEAA
CKYEEAA
None
None

Comment: The api caps the total results returned by that method.  You cant get a million rows back. if thats what your after google doesnt want you harvesting their data.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Is there any other way to fetch the channel details of news category? @DaImTo